# FileNotFoundError: Entity folder does not exist! in Google Colab

Tags: nlp, pytorch, google-colaboratory, torchvision, torchtext

Can anyone help me in sorting out this issue?
When I run these lines in Colab

:param files_name: containing training and validation samples list file.
:param boxes_and_transcripts_folder: gt or ocr result containing transcripts, boxes and box entity type (optional).
:param images_folder: whole images file folder
:param entities_folder: exactly entity type and entity value of documents, containing json format file
:param iob_tagging_type: 'box_level', 'document_level', 'box_and_within_box_level'
:param resized_image_size: resize whole image size, (w, h)
:param keep_ratio: TODO implement this parames
:param ignore_error:
:param training: True for train and validation mode, False for test mode. True will also load labels, and files_name and entities_file must be set.
'''
class PICKDataset(Dataset):

```
    def __init__(self, files_name: str = None,
                 boxes_and_transcripts_folder: str = 'boxes_and_transcripts',
                 images_folder: str = 'images',
                 entities_folder: str = 'entities',
                 iob_tagging_type: str = 'box_and_within_box_level',
                 resized_image_size: Tuple[int, int] = (480, 960),
                 keep_ratio: bool = True,
                 ignore_error: bool = False,
                 training: bool = True
                 ):
        
        super().__init__()
        self._image_ext = None
        self._ann_ext = None
        self.iob_tagging_type = iob_tagging_type
        self.keep_ratio = keep_ratio
        self.ignore_error = ignore_error
        self.training = training
        assert resized_image_size and len(resized_image_size) == 2, 'resized image size not be set.'
        self.resized_image_size = tuple(resized_image_size)  # (w, h)

        if self.training:  # used for train and validation mode
            self.files_name = Path(files_name)
            self.data_root = self.files_name.parent
            self.boxes_and_transcripts_folder: Path = self.data_root.joinpath(boxes_and_transcripts_folder)
            self.images_folder: Path = self.data_root.joinpath(images_folder)
            self.entities_folder: Path = self.data_root.joinpath(entities_folder)
            if self.iob_tagging_type != 'box_level':
                if not self.entities_folder.exists():
                    raise FileNotFoundError('Entity folder is not exist!')
```

I get this error

```
RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 0xe but this version of numpy is 0xd
[2022-02-26 13:17:11,933 - train - INFO] - Distributed GPU training model start...
[2022-02-26 13:17:11,933 - train - INFO] - [Process 306] Initializing process group with: {'MASTER_ADDR': '127.0.0.1', 'MASTER_PORT': '29500', 'RANK': '0', 'WORLD_SIZE': '1'}
[2022-02-26 13:17:11,934 - train - INFO] - [Process 306] world_size = 1, rank = 0, backend=nccl
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 162, in <module>
    entry_point(config)
  File "train.py", line 126, in entry_point
    main(config, local_master, logger if local_master else None)
  File "train.py", line 34, in main
    train_dataset = config.init_obj('train_dataset', pick_dataset_module)
  File "/content/PICK-pytorch/parse_config.py", line 105, in init_obj
    return getattr(module, module_name)(*args, **module_args)
  File "/content/PICK-pytorch/data_utils/pick_dataset.py", line 66, in __init__
    raise FileNotFoundError('Entity folder is not exist!')
FileNotFoundError: Entity folder is not exist!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/distributed/launch.py", line 263, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/distributed/launch.py", line 259, in main
    cmd=cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/usr/bin/python3', '-u', 'train.py', '--local_rank=0', '-c', 'config.json', '-d', '0', '--local_world_size', '1']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

What I have tried
Changing inputfilepath in PICKDataset, remving lines which rise error.

[Complete Notebook](https://github.com/mrm202/Personal-Projects/blob/main/information_extract_from_invoice_.ipynb)

Answer (score 1):

There is error in https://github.com/wenwenyu/PICK-pytorch/blob/master/config.json file. you have to change the path of data as per your working directory. Check line number 61 to 64 and 73 to 76.